# How do i get the text of each td in each tr of each tables using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i get the text of each `td` in each `tr` of each `table`?

i tried the code below but didn't work as expected.

HTML CODE

```js
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btn").click(function () {
            var array1 = [];
            $(".normaltable").each(function (index, object) {
                var tableData = {};
                tableData.datetime = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
                tableData.item = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();
                tableData.p1 = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text().trim();
                tableData.nt = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text().trim();
                array1.push(tableData);                   
            });    
            alert(JSON.stringify(array1));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="title">Group A</h2>
    <table class="normaltable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header0">
                <th class="datetime first">Date</th>
                <th class="item">Item</th>
                <th class="p1">P1</th>
                <th class="nt">NT</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="rw">
                <td class="datetime">09/01/20 19:33</td>
                <td class="item"><a><span class="tm"><span >Rice</span></span></a></td>
                <td class="p1 ">0:1</td>
                <td class="nt ftx">3:1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rw">
                 <td class="datetime">09/01/20 19:33</td>
                 <td class="item"><a><span class="tm"><span >Meat</span></span></a></td>
                 <td class="p1 ">0:2</td>
                 <td class="nt ftx ">8:1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rw">
                 <td class="datetime">09/01/20 19:33</td>
                 <td class="item"><a><span class="tm"><span >Wheat</span></span></a></td>
                 <td class="p1 ">0:1</td>
                 <td class="nt ftx ">3:1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        
    <h2 class="title">Group B</h2>
    <table class="normaltable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header0">
                <th class="datetime first">Date</th>
                <th class="item">Item</th>
                <th class="p1">P1</th>
                <th class="nt">NT</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="rw">
                <td class="datetime">10/01/20 19:33</td>
                <td class="item"><a><span class="tm"><span >Beans</span></span></a></td>
                <td class="p1 ">1:1</td>
                <td class="nt ftx ">2:1</td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="rw">
                 <td class="datetime">10/01/20 19:33</td>
                 <td class="item"><a><span class="tm"><span >Water</span></span></a></td>
                 <td class="p1 ">3:1</td>
                 <td class="nt ftx ">1:1</td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="rw">
                 <td class="datetime">10/01/20 19:33</td>
                 <td class="item"><a><span class="tm"><span >Melon</span></span></a></td>
                 <td class="p1 ">4:1</td>
                 <td class="nt ftx ">5:1</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        
        
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="btn" />
```

I got this

```
[
    {"datetime":"09/01/20 19:33","item":"Rice","p1":"0:1","nt":"3:1"},
    {"datetime":"10/01/20 19:33","item":"Beans","p1":"1:1","nt":"2:1"}
  ]
```

I expected this

```
[
    {"datetime":"09/01/20 19:33","item":"Rice","p1":"0:1","nt":"3:1"},
    {"datetime":"09/01/20 19:33","item":"Meat","p1":"0:2","nt":"8:1"},         
    {"datetime":"09/01/20 19:33","item":"Wheat","p1":"0:1","nt":"3:1"},
    {"datetime":"10/01/20 19:33","item":"Beans","p1":"1:1","nt":"2:1"},
    {"datetime":"10/01/20 19:33","item":"Water","p1":"3:1","nt":"1:1"},
    {"datetime":"10/01/20 19:33","item":"Melon","p1":"4:1","nt":"5:1"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand all you really need to change is `$(".normaltable").each(function(index, object) {` to `$(".normaltable tbody tr").each(function(index, object) {` then you should get what you wish.

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id*=btn").click(function() {
    var array1 = [];

    $(".normaltable tbody tr").each(function(index, object) {
  
      var tableData = {};
      
      tableData.datetime = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();

      tableData.match = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();

      tableData.p1 = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text().trim();

      tableData.nt = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text().trim();

      array1.push(tableData);

    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array1));
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="normaltable">

  <thead>

    <tr class="header0">
      <th class="datetime first">Date</th>
      <th class="item">Item</th>
      <th class="p1">P1</th>
      <th class="nt">NT</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>



  <tbody>

    <tr class="rw">
      <td class="datetime">09/01/20 19:33</td>
      <td class="item">


        <a>
          <span class="tm">
                            <span >
                                Rice
                            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="p1 ">0:1</td>
      <td class="nt ftx">3:1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rw">
      <td class="datetime">09/01/20 19:33</td>
      <td class="item">


        <a>
          <span class="tm">
                            <span >
                                Meat
                            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="p1 ">0:2</td>
      <td class="nt ftx ">8:1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rw">
      <td class="datetime">09/01/20 19:33</td>
      <td class="item">


        <a>
          <span class="tm">
                            <span >
                                Wheat
                            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="p1 ">0:1</td>
      <td class="nt ftx ">3:1</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>



</table>

<h2 class="title">Group B</h2>

<table class="normaltable">

  <thead>

    <tr class="header0">
      <th class="datetime first">Date</th>
      <th class="item">Item</th>
      <th class="p1">P1</th>
      <th class="nt">NT</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>



  <tbody>

    <tr class="rw">
      <td class="datetime">10/01/20 19:33</td>
      <td class="item">


        <a>
          <span class="tm">
                            <span >
                                Beans
                            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="p1 ">1:1</td>
      <td class="nt ftx ">2:1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rw">
      <td class="datetime">10/01/20 19:33</td>
      <td class="item">


        <a>
          <span class="tm">
                            <span >
                                Water
                            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="p1 ">3:1</td>
      <td class="nt ftx ">1:1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rw">
      <td class="datetime">10/01/20 19:33</td>
      <td class="item">


        <a>
          <span class="tm">
                            <span >
                                Melon
                            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="p1 ">4:1</td>
      <td class="nt ftx ">5:1</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>



</table>

<button id="btn1">run</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to find every table whom have same class name `normalTable`.
Then try to find each row of the each table.
After getting rows try to find text of `td` then store it in `array`

`var array1 = [];
$('.normalTable tbody tr').each(function() {
var $tds = $(this).find('td');
if($tds.length != 0) {
var $currText = $tds.eq(0).text();
array1.push($currText);
}
});`

Comment: `$('.normalTable tr')` would also include the data from the `thead`

Comment: Yes I agreed with your question so I just updated an answer